# Wordpress - custom admin panel link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a new item to WP admin panel which should be visible only for me - admin with a specific email address. I'm using on client sites two different email addresses:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;

if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && $current_user_email == 'mail1@example.com' || $current_user_email == 'mail2@example.com' ) {
    function custom_toolbar_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {

        $url = esc_url( admin_url( '/theme-editor.php' ) );

        $args = array(
            'id'    => 'theme-editor',
            'title' => 'EDITOR',
            'href'  => $url
        );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $args ); 
    }   
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_toolbar_link', 999 );
```

This is working good, but other admin users are getting this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'custom_toolbar_link' not found or invalid function
>   name in
>   /data/5/e/5e7d2c4b-ecbe-4661-b60c-fad9d09a505d/example.com/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with `add_action` should be inside the `if` statement, because the function `custom_toolbar_link` is only defined for certain users.